# Linking data between two Excel files in SharePoint Online / OneDrive, without having to open both files

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, onedrive

I am trying to create two cooperating files, both sitting in SharePoint Online / Onedrive :

- Multiple "type A" files, using centrally produced data
- One "type B" file, handled by a central team, containing data that will be recovered by all "type A" files

My issue is that the link between files constantly breaks if I don't have both files opened. I'll give you some details below, but my research has shown that it seems to be a common issue, and I couldn't find a satisfactory solution. I've seen suggestions about PowerQuery though

My process: when I create my links in "type A" file (with both files open), it looks like this

```
=formula('fileB.xlsx'!TableName[#Data])
```

Everything works fine like this, with both files opened. Close & Save.

Then, user A opens his type A file (without opening file B). EXCEL asks me to "update values", every formula is now broken. Every link has now become :

```
=formula('https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/fileAddress/fileB.xlsx'!TableName[#Data])
```

Which should work! But it doesn't

1. when checking the workbooks links, I can check the state of the link, which turns to "OK" after the check. But every value is still broken.
2. if I change some folder name in SharePoint online, thus modifying the "fileAdress", it is automatically and instantly reproduced in my file A formulas... So the link definitely exists..

Until I open file B, which makes the formula go back to their previous state and fixes the values.

Oh yeah, also I put all my file B data in one sheet, otherwise we had another error message asking to select the right worksheet, when I was using 3 ... And it shouldn't matter cause all my tables are correctly named and the link doesn't even use the worksheet name..